# In Aurelia Router is it possible to get notified when the user attempts to navigate to the same page?

Tags: aurelia

The [Aurelia Router](https://aurelia.io/docs/routing/configuration) fires off events in the [EventAggregator](https://aurelia.io/docs/fundamentals/cheat-sheet#the-event-aggregator) which I can subscribe to. My code subscribes to the `router:navigation:processing` event so that whenever a user clicks a route my navigation menu closes.

```
eventAggregator.subscribe('router:navigation:processing', e => menu.close());
```

The problem is that when the user is on the page in which they are trying to navigate to, then the menu stays open. I would like to close the menu when they select the same page in which they are currently on.

I would also like to mention that my menu links look like this:

```
<a route-href="route:showcase" class="menu-item">Showcase</a>
```

I would like keep my links like this if at all possible because I like how the `aurelia-router` binds the `href` address automagically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no real built-in mechanism for this. `history-browser` is responsible for intercepting click events on anchor tags and sending the url fragment to the routeHandler.

It only does this if the new fragment is different from the old fragment (**or** if the navigationStategy is 'replace'); if not, the operation is aborted long before the router is even involved.

Depending on how frequently you need this and how much time it's worth investing in, etc, some options come to mind:

- Add a `click.trigger` event listener on the anchor tag. On click, your check would be a little hacky (it's mimicking what the framework does) on an injected `BrowserHistory`: `history._getFragment(DefaultLinkHandler.getEventInfo(event).href) === history.fragment`. If this evaluates to true, you're on the same page and the router won't do anything, so it's your turn to publish something to EventAggregator.
- Or a simpler (but more prone to issues / edge cases) alternative to the above: register a click event that simply compares the `href` attribute to `window.location.href` or some of its friends.
- Use `navigationStrategy.replace` (would not recommend as it redoes your whole component for no reason, but it's an option)
- Override the `BrowserHistory` class's `navigate()` method that publishes to EventAggregator (line 138 or something of index.js) when `this.fragment === fragment` to do this globally, and register it with DI as `History`

Answer (score 1):

I marked Fred Kleuver's answer as the answer because I feel like his ways though are more difficult to implement are probably a lot more powerful. But also you need an understanding of the inner workings of the framework.  In the end I just implemented a hacky way of solving my issue.  I created a custom element called `navigate-to-page-link`.

*navigate-to-page-link.ts*

```
import { bindable, autoinject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { Store } from 'aurelia-store';
import { State } from '@src/state/state';
import { MenuStateActions } from '../menu-state';

@autoinject()
export class NavigateToPageLink{
  @bindable route: string;
  @bindable name: string;

  constructor(private store: Store<State>){}

  closeMenu(){
    this.store.dispatch(MenuStateActions.close);
    return true;
  }
}
```

*navigate-to-page-link.html*

```
<template>
  <a route-href="route.bind: route" click.delegate="closeMenu()" class="menu-item">${name}</a>
</template>
```

So, basically I'm using the `aurelia-store` to open and close my menu. Also, I need to `return true` from the `click.delegate` method in order for the `href` link to navigate.

Inside my menu I use this element like so:

```
<require from="./navigate-to-page-link"></require>
<navigate-to-page-link route="home" name="Home"></navigate-to-page-link>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for sharing what you ended up doing. I may have misunderstood your constraints a bit. Are you simply looking to close the menu whenever you navigate, regardless of whether you're navigating to the current page or another one? In that case I would have suggested far cleaner solution than the ones I suggested now :)